# Get Custom URL For Custom Taxonomy

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy

I've got a custom post type called productpopups, and to sort them I have a custom taxonomy called productcategory. The post type has it's own special template (single-productpopup.php) and I'm trying to show each products category with a link to the category. The problem I have is the following:

The link for each productcategory is say `example.com/productcategory/category` but the page I want to link it to is actually `example.com/category`

So I made up this:

```
<p>Categories: 
<?php 
$categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'productcategory' ); 
foreach( $categories as $category ) { 
    echo '<a href="http://example.com/'.$category->slug.'">'.$category->name.'</a>, '; 
}
?>
</p>
```

This works because the pages I have set up use the same slugs as the productcategory, but its hacky and one slip (like a typo) will break it.

What I'd essential like to do is add a custom field to the taxonomy where I can specify the page url, and then be able to call that instead of the `http://example.com/.$category->slug`

Is this possible?

**Edit for additional clarification:** Forget the fact it's a url, I need a field where I can input data, and can be queried on a by product basis, so that if a product has multiple categories, the information for each can be found. For example say Product A has two categories, one and two, a table like this would be able to be formed:

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+
| Name      | Category | Custom Value |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
| Product A | C 001    | CV 001       |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
| Product A | C 002    | CV 002       |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that I finally came up with to fix the problem!

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$catresult = array();
$postid = get_the_ID();
$query1c = "SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_terms.`name` AS `Category`, wp_pods_productcategory.`pc-url` AS `Url`
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
INNER JOIN wp_terms ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_terms.term_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_pods_productcategory ON wp_pods_productcategory.id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'productcategory' AND wp_posts.ID =$postid
ORDER BY wp_terms.`name` ASC";
$categories = $wpdb->get_results( $query1c );
foreach ( $categories as $category )
{
array_push( $catresult, "<a href='".$category->Url."'>".$category->Category."</a>" );
}
echo implode(', ', $catresult);
?>
```

So how does this work?

`<?php` This is the opening tag so the server knows what comes next is `php`.

`global $wpdb` Here we tell the server that we'll be connecting to the WordPress Database.

`$catresult = array();` Here we create the array we'll use to store the data.

`$postid = get_the_ID();` Here we get the post id to be able to filter the query.

`$query1c = "SELECT....` Here we put the query, which selects the fields we want, filtered by `wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'productcategory'` and `wp_posts.ID =$postid` (this is where we use the `$postid` from before) and ordered by `wp_terms.name ASC`.

`$categories = $wpdb->get_results( $query1c )` This runs the query, and saves the raw data to `$categories`.

Now we need to convert the raw data into something we can use, the raw data is currently saved as `$categories` but we need each result individually so we put:

`foreach ( $categories as $category)` Here one result gets known as `$category`

`array_push( $catresult, "<a href='".$category->Url."'>".$category->Category."</a>" )` Here we 'push' each result individually to the array we created earlier - `$catresult`. Each result has been prepared with its link (`<a>` tag).

One last thing - as we want these categories in a list, it would look better if they where separated by commas! So:

`echo implode(', ', $catresult)` So here we 'implode' the array, which means we put something between each result of the array, which in this case is a comma followed by a space. This is then printed to the page by using the `echo` command.

Finally `?>` tells the server to close this `php` section.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to come to the party late. Here is my solution

```
<?php
    //Retrieve the terms in productcategory taxonomy with posts (not empty)
    $terms = get_terms( array ( 'taxonomy' => 'productcategory', 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'description', 'order' => 'ASC' ));

    //loop through each term to get its attributes
    foreach ($terms as $term) {

        //Uncomment below code to see all the available attributes.
        //var_dump($term); 
        //die();
        $name        = $term->name;

        //PHP -> Store the link in variable to reuse
        //to get the link for the the particular term; you need to have the slug and pass it into the get_term_link() function.
        //the second argument is the taxonomy name in this case productcategory.
        $cat_link    = get_term_link( $term->slug, 'productcategory' );

?>

<a href="<?php echo $cat_link; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a>

<?php
    }

?>
```

Comment: Please take a few minutes and edit the code to explain what is going on.  Currently this is a code dump.

Comment: I hope that better explains the solution

Comment: Amazing solution. Worked like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the taxonomy yourself, you could set your own slug for the custom taxonomy. For Example:

```
register_taxonomy(
    'productcategory',
    array(
        'productpopups',
    ),
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Categories', 'text-domain'),
        ),

        // --- set taxonomy slug ---
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => '%productcategory%',  // set taxonomy slug
            'with_front' => false,          // set this to false
        )
        // -------------------------
    )
);

flush_rewrite_rules();  // <-- don't forget to add this line of code!
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've done - the thing is I have a custom page for each of these categories and I want to link to those, instead of a page where all the products are listed automatically.